# Create a scroll from left-to-right for linearLayout items

Tags: android

is it possible to create a scroll-"event" for items inside a LinearLayout?

My main_activity.xml:

```
             <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
```

I have here one LinearLayout for all items, inside this LinearLayout for each items a Linearlayout and inside 1 or more Textviews.

How can I create a swipe from left to right for the items?

Something like:

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there has to be a simpler way of doing this with GridLayout, what you're looking for is the HorizontalScrollView. Just embed the linearlayouts into it, and it should work.